# Limiting SQL results based on JOIN ON parameter(s) or WHERE parameter(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to determine if there are any known benefits of using selection parameters in a MySQL query in either the JOIN ON clause or within the WHERE clause itself.

I am certain and aware the results returned are the same and while testing locally the "query time" appears to be almost negligible but wanted to see if there are any expert opinions.

Are there are differences in these two in the backend and if so, which is preferred?

### v1

```
SELECT
  *
FROM users a
JOIN user_photos b ON (b.userid = a.userid)
WHERE
  a.userid = 12345
  AND b.photo_type = 1
```

### or v2

```
SELECT
  *
FROM users a
JOIN user_photos b ON (b.userid = a.userid AND b.photo_type = 1)
WHERE
  a.userid = 12345
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` and see if the execution plans are different.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference in an INNER JOIN. There would be in a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I tend to only use field to field criteria in the `JOIN` clause, anything else, or when constants are involved, tend to go in to the WHERE clause.  With a regular, `INNER` join, they are probably functionally identical.

Comment: @Barmar - explain exec plans are identical - based on the results I did believe they were the same but wondered if any backend stuff was changing based on the way the query was laid out

Comment: If the execution plan is the same, then it's doing the same work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there's no Outer Join there will be no difference regarding the result set.
And all not totally stupid optimizers will treat both versions exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Both queries will give same performance and will be executed in same amount of time. Execution plan for both of them is same

V1 Execution plan
[image]

V2 Execution plan
[image]

Comment: interesting software - what is it if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: its sql server management studio(SSMS). You have an option called include execution plan which helps to generate an execution plan for your query and you can optimize your query performance using this.